# How can I specify a custom icon for different folders in Unity?

Tags: unity, icons, directory

I would like to have certain folders have their own custom icons. I've been doing this with scripts for some time, by creating .desktop files like the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Script
Exec="/home/me/script.sh"
Icon=/home/me/foo.ico
Terminal=false
```

From what I can tell, there is a way to do this with directories too, but the file extension has to be .directory instead of .desktop. But where are the instructions for this located? The ones located on [Free Desktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) don't specify the format for the directory file, and I can't find any others on the Internet. When I've just put something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Directory
Name=My Directory
Path=/home/me/mydir
Icon=/home/me/mydir.ico
```

it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most basic version of a .desktop file to open a directory:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Exec=nautilus /path/to/your/directory
Icon=/path/to/your/icon
Type=Application
```

So the type still should to be set to `Type=Application`.

You can make a .desktop file do anything, just by setting the right command in the `Exec=` line. The command to open a folder with nautilus is

```
nautilus /path/to/folder
```

Look inside the file `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`. It says:

```
Type=Application
```

and

```
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
```

#### Note

Be aware of the fact that the starter *is not your folder*, like the starter to your script is not your script, it only contains the command to open it.

#### Alternative

Having said that, there is a much easier way to give a folder another icon:

- right click on the folder > properties
- click on the icon
- browse to the icon of your choice, set it

Done:

[image]  [image]